# No selection to install SSIS, SSRS and SSAS

Tags: sql-server, business-intelligence, sql-server-2012

Goal:
Install Developer SQL Server 2012+ Business intelligence and its SSIS, SSRS and SSAS in my computer.

Problem:
Can't find the settings or something similar in the install selection  to install SSIS, SSRS and SSAS in my computer.

Before doing the installation, a screen was displayed with selection of feature. Look at the picture.

[image]

Comment: This looks like you selected "add features to an existing instance" and those features are already installed. This also looks like Developer Edition, not Buisiness Intelligence Edition.

Comment: If I understand from your side, BI development studio don't include in the Developer edition 2012?

Comment: Are you talking about BIDS? I don't think this concept exists anymore for SQL Server 2012. You can install [SQL Server Data Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/tools.aspx) separately and you can [read about it here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272686(v=vs.103).aspx). Or use a previous version of BIDS, but I don't think it will understand any of the new features.

Comment: Yes, it is about BIDS. If BIDS don't exist in SQL server 2012, what will be instead? :O

Comment: I thought I just commented on that.

Comment: It sounds strange when I can go finding books for instance reporting service 2012 "http://www.amazon.com/Professional-Microsoft-Server-Reporting-Services/dp/1118101111/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1340565341&sr=8-1&keywords=Professional+Microsoft+SQL+Server+2012+Reporting+Services"

Comment: Not sure I follow. What does that book have to do with BIDS? Have you looked at SQL Server Data Tools at all? How about http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220460.aspx and http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159221.aspx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is in the Developer Ed of VS 2012.  You just have to look for it now because they separated it out into a different place.  Look for SQL Server Data Tools 2012 in your start menus and launch it; however, if it does not come up, then navigate to find your VS 2010 and start it up and load up your Integration Services project in there.  This is what I had to do.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is Sql Server Data Tools. Bear in mind that there are 2 versions of the Data Tools - someone called them data tools - db and data tools - BI for lack of a better term.

Data Tools - BI are the compact version of Visual Studio 2010 with all the required project types for ssrs ssis and ssas.

Data Tools - db that you can get [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh297027) provide connectivity to sql server via the Data Tools - (BIDS in sql server 2008).

The selection is disabled as Aaron said due to the fact that Intergration Services (SSIS), Analysis Services(SSAS) and reporting Services (SSRS) are already installed.

Answer (score 0):

You want 2012,  since others provided that information here is instead for you and OTHERS to get  2014 Data Tools and 2008 BIDS :

1. SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) for SQL Server 2014 
    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/jj650015
2. OLD 2008 for some of you still wanting it / using sql server 2008....

For getting BIDS With SQL Server 2008 Developer Edition, you simply want to search for

```
"SQL Server Business Intelligence Development Studio"
```

[image]

This will open the Visual Studio 2008 Shell of which you then click on Create - Project

[image]

Now you have all your options.  This is right next to Microsoft SQL Server (SSMS)